# Why use getappletcontext().showstatus to change status in java applets

Tags: java, applet

I was learning Applets in Java and couldn't understand the usage of `getappletcontext().showStatus()` everywhere in the textbook.

But I see that it has been used in Applet programs many times.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: couldn't frame the question right, have a look at it now @immibis

Comment: Is "Because there's no other way to do what it does" not a good reason?

Comment: can't i use Applet.showStatus("<text>") to do it directly?

Comment: Of course, if you have a reference to the Applet. Sometimes it's more convenient to pass the context around rather than the applet itself.

Comment: *"couldn't understand the usage of .. showStatus()"* See [`Applet.showStatus(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#showStatus-java.lang.String-): Requests that the argument string be displayed in the "status window". Many browsers and applet viewers provide such a window, where the application can inform users of its current state. -- Now, to explain that a bit more.  This 'message' *might* appear in a single line bar that pops up at the bottom of the browser window.  They used to be a permanent bar, then became optional, then defaulted to 'off' - not ..

Comment: .. not much use, in the modern era.  On the other hand, neither are applets themselves and.. Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).